# CCAnimation not working properly

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I need help

I'm developing a simple 2d game where the character walks right and left.

I am using sneakyjoystick and walking animation of 6 frames which I apply CCAnimation

the issue I have is, when I animation is called from the joystick update method the animation starts only when I release the left or right button from left joystick... it seems to me I am missing something simple but I can't figure out...

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime
{
    CGPoint scaleVelocity = ccpMult(leftJoystick.velocity, 100);
    CGPoint oldPosition = [self.Bartender position];
    CGPoint newPosition = ccp(self.Bartender.position.x + scaleVelocity.x * deltaTime, self.Bartender.position.y + scaleVelocity.y * deltaTime);


    [self.Bartender setPosition:newPosition];
    if (oldPosition.x > newPosition.x) {

        [self.Bartender stopAllActions];
        self.Bartender.flipX = YES;
        [self GoWalk];

    } else if (oldPosition.x == newPosition.x) {

        // Intentionally do nothing to preserve orientation at start of scene!
        NSLog(@"equal");

    } else {

        [self.Bartender stopAllActions];
        self.Bartender.flipX = NO;
        [self GoWalk];
    }


    /*
     if(oldPosition.x > newPosition.x)
     {
     aChar.flipX = YES;
     }
     else if(aChar.flipX == YES)
     {
     aChar.flipX = NO;
     }

     if(jumpButton.active == YES)
     {
     CCLOG(@"jump pressed");
     }
     if(attackButton.active == YES)
     {
     CCLOG(@"attack pressed");
     }

     [aChar setPosition:newPosition];*/

}


-(void)GoStand
{
    self.StandAnimation = [CCAnimation animation];

    [self.StandAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"AStand1.png"]];
    [self.StandAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"AStand1.png"]];
    [self.StandAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"Walk4.png"]];
    [self.StandAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"AStand1.png"]];
    [self.StandAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"AStand1.png"]];

    id animatedAction = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:0.8f animation:self.StandAnimation restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
    id repeatAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animatedAction];
    [self.Bartender runAction:repeatAction];
}

-(void)GoWalk
{
    self.WalkAnimation = [CCAnimation animation];

    [self.WalkAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"Walk1.png"]];
    [self.WalkAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"Walk2.png"]];
    [self.WalkAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"Walk3.png"]];
    [self.WalkAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"Walk4.png"]];
    [self.WalkAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"Walk5.png"]];
    [self.WalkAnimation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"Walk6.png"]];

    id animatedAction = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:0.8f animation:self.WalkAnimation restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
    id repeatAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animatedAction];
    [self.Bartender runAction:repeatAction];
}
```

Anybody?

Comment: it is so cool to post commented code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you start your animation too often. About 60 time a second, if your fps is 60. So you are trying to run action on your node every tick.

Comment: I got it, due your question I created a bit control by adding a BOOL property in the CCLayer and it worked.